# Orika fails during maven test but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, junit4, orika

When trying to run a maven build (`mvn clean install`) to test my integration, tests, I obtained the following error:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.219 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.ots.gateway.service.OtsMobTokensServiceTest
[ERROR] testFindByOttNumber(com.ots.gateway.service.OtsMobTokensServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0.219 s  <<< ERROR!
ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: 'destinationClass' is required
     at com.ots.gateway.service.OtsMobTokensServiceTest.testFindByOttNumber(OtsMobTokensServiceTest.java:26)
```

> **JDK**: jdk1.8.0_144
>
> **Maven**: apache-maven-3.2.5
>
> **Orika**: 1.5.1

I believe it is happening due to the use of Orika. Can someone please help on this?

My code:

```
/**
     * Maps a source object(Entity or DTO) to its matching target(Entity or DTO).
     *
     * @param <T> the generic type
     * @param o - entity or dto
     * @return the t
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected <T extends Object> T map(Object o) {
        T mappedObject = null;
        Mapper mapperProvider = mapperFactory.createMapper(o);
        try {
            if (SanityCheck.isValid(mapperProvider)) {
                mappedObject = (T) mapperProvider.map(o);
            } else {
                if(SanityCheck.isValid(o)){
                    LOGGER.error("No Mapper found for object: " + o.getClass().getName() + " Service: "
                            + this.getClass().getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Casting error", e);
        }
        return mappedObject;
    }
```

Comment: It's indeed due to the way you do the mapping with Orika, but it's difficult to give you an answer without seeing your code. It seems that you're not providing the destination class of the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out how to solve it by making use of the surefire plugin:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.20.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The issue was that I am using org.reflections in my project to load all the entities and dtos of my packages. When running maven tests, it does not work. By not using the system class loader, the tests succeeded. More info can be found here:
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html